# Forcing two WPF controls to have the same width while maintaining auto sizing from xaml (Both controls have greater of two width)

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to define a 1x3 grid where the first and third  columns widths auto-size to fit their contents but maintain equal widths. I figured I could achieve this by binding each ColumnDefinition's MinWidth property to be the other columns ActualWidth. But it does not seem to work. Can someone explain why the following code does not work?

'''

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type edvm:NodeViewModel}">
   <Grid">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
             x:Name="inCol"
             Width="Auto"
             MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=outCol, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition 
            Width="*" 
            MinWidth="25" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            x:Name="outCol"
            Width="Auto"
            MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=inCol, Path=ActualWidth}" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `SharedSizeGroup` property of both ColumnDefinitions. That would implicitly also set `Width="Auto"`.

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="OuterColumns"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="25"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="OuterColumns"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the tip on Grid.SharedSizeScope it's exactly what I was looking for.  I am still wondering why the code I posted does not work as I would expect do you have any ideas?

Comment: No idea. When I bind a TextBlock to the ActualWidth of one of the columns, it shows zero.